# Sending Transactional Email via SendGrid with jQuery & Google Tag Manager

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to send an email using a google tag manager custom html tag when certain events are triggered.

This is the code (XXXXX for omission where needed)

```
<script>
    var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
        "authorization": "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "content-type": "application/json"
      },
      "processData": false,
      "data": "{\"personalizations\":[{\"to\":[{\"email\":\"XXXXXXXXXX\",\"name\":\"John Doe\"}],\"dynamic_template_data\":{\"verb\":\"yes\",\"adjective\":\"test\",\"noun\":\"\",\"currentDayofWeek\":\"\"},\"subject\":\"Hello, World!\"}],\"from\":{\"email\":\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\",\"name\":\"John Doe\"},\"reply_to\":{\"email\":\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\",\"name\":\"John Doe\"},\"template_id\":\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}"
    }

    jQuery.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
    </script>
```

Now This block (minus the script tags) runs when using the built in send grid "try it out" feature. Why will this not work from GTM?

Comment: Are you getting anything in the console? If you aren't getting anything from the `console.log(response);`, GTM isn't firing the tag at all.

Comment: I do not get anything when I compile the code on an online compiler

Comment: Have you used GTM's `Preview Mode` to see if your tag is actually firing when its criteria are met?

Comment: Yes, the tag is firing with no errors as far as GTM goes

Comment: How about jQuery? Is it installed on your site? The code you provided relies on jQuery in order to make the POST request.

Comment: I ran jQuery.fn.jquery in the console on firefox and it appears V. 1.12.4 is loaded on the site

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this code might be getting added and run prior to jQuery being ready. Try the following update to the code:

```
<script>
  jQuery(function() {
    var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
        "authorization": "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "content-type": "application/json"
      },
      "processData": false,
      "data": "{\"personalizations\":[{\"to\":[{\"email\":\"XXXXXXXXXX\",\"name\":\"John Doe\"}],\"dynamic_template_data\":{\"verb\":\"yes\",\"adjective\":\"test\",\"noun\":\"\",\"currentDayofWeek\":\"\"},\"subject\":\"Hello, World!\"}],\"from\":{\"email\":\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\",\"name\":\"John Doe\"},\"reply_to\":{\"email\":\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\",\"name\":\"John Doe\"},\"template_id\":\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}"
    }

    jQuery.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log("SendGrid Response:", response);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Try that and see if you see anything in the console labeled "SendGrid Response:". That'll definitively let us know if this script is running at all.

Comment: So this still does not post anything to the console